# plotly density_heatmap output html is too big

Tags: plotly

I have a data frame with 25million rows with x,y coordinate and measures for creating a 2d heatmap.

```
fig = px.density_heatmap(df,
x="x",
y="y",
z="something",
nbinsx=600,
nbinsy=600,
histfunc='sum')
```

The plot is saved as html for offline viewing.

The output html is huge as it has all the 25million x and y values.
shouldn't it reduce to 600x600 which is the number of bins?
It takes huge ram for browser to render it. loading 2 of these makes it exceed ram.